# App\Entity\Article object not found by the @paramconverter annotation Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I try to be redirected after modifying the comment but I have the error App \ Entity \ Article object not found by the @paramconverter annotation do you have any idea of ​​the problem?

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/modifier", name="comment_edit", methods={"GET","POST"}, requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Article $article
 * @param Comment $comment
 * @param LinkRepository $linkRepository
 * @param MoreRepository $moreRepository
 * @return Response
 */
public function editComment(Request $request,Article $article, Comment $comment, LinkRepository $linkRepository,MoreRepository $moreRepository): Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('article_details',['id' => $article->getId()]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the namespace of the object Article? Do you use an `import` to reference the object origin? It looks like you didnt import this object, so it use the default namespace. Try to use `import` for `Device` or use full class path in the comment `@param Full\Class\Path\Device`

Comment: Do you have a `use App\Entity\Article;` line ? (or whatever the namespace to your Article Entity is)

Comment: yes i use App\Entity\Article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the name of you function (`editComment`) it seems like your are passing the `id` of the `Comment` rather thant the `id` of the `Article`.

Wihtout any explicit explanation, Symfony tries to find the `id` (name of your URL parameter) of you first Entity in the controller arguments (an `Article`) but can't find it since you seem to be trying to modify a `Comment`.

Since you want to have several objects hydrated by the URL parameter, you should explicitly explain how to find each of them :

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Entity;

/**
 * @Route("/{id_comment}/modifier", name="edit_comment")
 * @Entity("comment", expr="repository.find(id_comment)")
 * @Entity("article", expr="repository.findArticleByCommentID(id_comment)")
 */
public function editComment(Request $request, Article $article, Comment $comment, LinkRepository $linkRepository, MoreRepository $moreRepository): Response
{
    // ...
```

And then create in your `ArticleRepository` a function named `findArticleByCommentID()`.

If you want only the `$comment` to be found via the Annotation, you can also do :

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id_comment}/modifier", name="edit_comment")
 * @Entity("comment", expr="repository.find(id_comment)")
 */
public function editComment(Request $request, Comment $comment, LinkRepository $linkRepository, MoreRepository $moreRepository): Response
{
    // Notice there isn't any Article in the controller arguments
    $article = $comment->getArticle();
    // ...
```

More on Parameter conversion here : https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html